# unittest - junit and Mockito. Test addNewAccount to Databases, f I need to remove/delete a account

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have written to Unit test - junit with Mockito library to test any methods, who save to databases new account - `addNewAccount` methods.
I would like to ask - if I need to add a method or what and how - to delete/remove an account, whos was added. and please show me what I can do it.
my unit test is:

```
 @Test
        public void shouldSaveaAccountToDb() {
            Account acc = new Account();
            acc.setUser(this.user);
            acc.setEmail(this.mail);
            String account = this.accountController.addNewAccount(this.user, this.mail);
            verify(this.accountRepepetytory)).save(Mockito.refEq(acc, new String[0]));
            Assert.assertThat(account, CoreMatchers.is("Account"));
        }
```

I also want to add a case with a null value and testing null and empty string. if you can any idea to add test case please tell me.

---

thank you very match for help. I improved my test.
I have also a method who testing with null value. This is the method.

```
   @Test
    public void SaveToDatabaseWithNull() {
        Account acc = new Account();
        String mail = null;
        user.setMail((String)mail);
        user.setUser(this.user);
        String account = this.accountController.addNewAccount(this.user, (String)mail);
        verify(this.accountRepetytory)).save(Mockito.refEq(uaccount, new String[0]));
        Assert.assertThataccountCoreMatchers.is("Account"));
    }
```

I also would like to ask, whether in these tests it is necessary to delete some values, adding a method that deletes the account. if I create an account in one method, do I have to delete it in some way and in which way? to test correctly with the null value in the later method.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you have some weaknesses that make you test britle and hard to understand:

#### Each test method should verify one single expectation only.

Your test verifies two things:

1. The code created an object of class `Account` that equals to the one created in the test method by the means of the `Account` classes implementation of `equals()`.
2. The return value of the method is a string with content `"Account"`.
   Problem of that is that the test does not explain *why* you expect that string.

So basically you should have separate methods to verify either behavior allowing for a better description of the tested behavior in the test method name.

#### reduce dependencies to unrelated code.

`Mockito.refEq()` relies on a (correct) implementation of the `equals` method in class `Account`. There is no quaratee that this method is actually implemented or (even worse) may need addioional configuration in future if an account gets more properties that are not allowed to be `null`.

The better way here is to use an `ArgumentCaptor` and verify the properties of the captures object:

```
@Test
    public void shouldPassAnAccountObjectWithNameAndEmailSetToDB() {
        ArgumentCaptor<Account> accountCaptor = 
             ArgumentCaptor.forClass(
                  Account.class);
        this.accountController.addNewAccount(
                  this.user, 
                  this.mail);
        verify(this.accountRepepetytory))
             .save(
                  accountCaptor.capture());
        Assert.assertThat(
                  "user", 
                  accountCaptor.getValue().getUser(), 
                  CoreMatchers.is(this.user));
        Assert.assertThat(
                  "email", 
                  accountCaptor.getValue().getEmail(), 
                  CoreMatchers.is(this.email));
    }
```